# Send an Email to Specific Column of a List via Site Workflow in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a List named Subscriber which contains following Columns:

1. Name
2. IsSubscribe (Yes/No)
3. Email

I want to send an Email via workflow where **To** email addresses should be selected from my List **Subscriber** column **Email** provided that **IsSubscriber** should be **Yes**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a SharePoint Designer Workflow for this list which will trigger when item is created.

Start with an IF condition, if IsSubscriber == Yes --> then send email.

For sending email, use the 'Send Email' activity. In the To field, make a selection for 'Email' column to send email to the emailid mentioned in this column. And then mention the subject, body.

Publish the workflow and you are done.

=== EDIT ===

Please follow this -

Open 'SharePoint Designer'

Click on 'Workflows' section

Click 'List Workflow' -> Select List

Add if condition, after that

Click on 'Action' -> Select 'Send An Email'

In 'To' -> Click on 'Address Book' -> Click 'Workflow Lookup for a User'

Select entries like

Data Source - Current Item

Field from source = Email

Return field as = string

Comment: How can I select Email Column in SharePoint designer??? When I am selecting Email Column then it started to ask me "Find the List Item" where it ask about Field and Value what should I write there ???

Comment: Baseer, I have modified my response. Please have a look if it hellps

Comment: Dear Clad,
I have followed the same steps in order to create workflow. I am creating site Workflow for your information. When I click on  'Workflow Lookup for a User' 
Data Source - Subscriber 

Field from source = Email

Return field as = string

then It ask for Find the list Item with two options Field and Value what should I write there???